# ImageMagick circular dstortion on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, imagemagick

I am working on an iOS project which uses ImageMagick. I wonder if it is possible to perform some circular distortions on an image, but not on the center of the image, rather in a point (x,y) and of a given radius R.

Any (constructive) responses are well appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the ImageMagick documentation? I presume you want to use ImageMagick to do this distortion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ImageMagick doesn't directly support doing a circular distortion at non-origin, you might want to pass in a sequence of commands to: a) add appropriate border to the image, b) do a circular distortion, c) get rid of the border added in (a). The size of the border is such that it effectively shifts the distortion origin to the desired place in the original image.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you very much

Comment: And by the way, is it possible to perform a non-circular distortion with Image Magick? Like oval-like distortions.